# Quickblox Android Push Notifications with app in the foreground

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I am using Quickblox in my app, but I have an issue with the push notifications.
I receive the notifications while the app is in the background or close.
But while I have the app opened if I receive a message from a conversation I don't receive any push notification.

I use QBMessageListener when the user is inside the conversation, and it works, but I don't know how to receive messages from other conversations to show a notification to the user.

I supposed I would receive a push notifications, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having same issue. Sometimes I'm not getting notification even the app is background or close. Let me know if you have any solutions..

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jatin, be sure that you make the logout from quickblox, they send the push notification just if the user is not logged in. Anyway, check the last release of the sdk (3.0), they have changed a lot of thing and they have included great things.

Comment: Thanks for  the replay. I will try it